# Update Google Map marker position value in mySQL by using PHP and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, google-maps

I need help with an issue I am facing with *updating my Google Map Marker position to mySQL*. **I want to send the latitude and longitude of this marker in the background (i.e with-out refreshing the page)**. I have used AJAX and PHP but no luck so far. It could be because I am a beginner  in both.

The following is my work:

The part that needs fixing in **driver.php**

```
/////Get latitude and longitude of the last created marker/////////
lg1= markerStart.getPosition().lng();
lt1= markerStart.getPosition().lat();

////I need help here- Please provide me with solution///////////
$.ajax({
url: "update.php",
type: "POST",
data: {'xCordinates': lg1,'yCordinates': lt1}
/*,
success: function () {
    alert("ok");// This works
}*/
});


//alert(lg1+","+lt1); // This works (I get accurate altitude and longitude)
```

**update.php**

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    $driverId    = $_SESSION['driver_id'];
    $driver_name = $_SESSION['name'];
    include "header.php"; // access database
    $xCordinates = $_POST['xCordinates']; // take value of xCordinates
    $yCordinates = $_POST['yCordinates']; // take value of yCordinates
    // Do not worry about the spelling mistakes below!
    $updatevalue = "UPDATE driver SET xCornidates='$xCordinates', yCornidates='$yCordinates' WHERE driver_id='$driverId'";
    $result1 = mysql_query($updatevalue) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

I would appreciate to get a solution from you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this, change

```
 $updatevalue = "UPDATE driver SET xCornidates='$xCordinates', yCornidates='$yCordinates' WHERE driver_id='$driverId'";
```

to

```
 $updatevalue = "UPDATE driver SET xCornidates=$xCordinates, yCornidates=$yCordinates WHERE driver_id=$driverId";
```

but consider restructuring to avoid sql injection.

Comment: alright, add `echo $updatevalue;` after this line  `$updatevalue = "UPDATE driver SET xCornidates=$xCordinates, yCornidates=$yCordinates WHERE driver_id=$driverId";` so as to see the query. Now use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to send the post request and get the response.

Comment: Oh, i see the column names is xCornidates and yCornidates, i guess this is a mistake or are they your real column names?

Comment: Hi Orion! Yes, They are actually the correct names. They were written mistakenly. Anyways, I have solved the issue by changing $driverId    = $_SESSION['driver_id']; to $driver_id    = $_SESSION['driver_id'];

Comment: Okay nice, but that seems strange though.